# Swift - Save new position of button/image after being dragged using Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data, uiview, save, uipangesturerecognizer

I am creating a new button programmatically which I can drag to the desired position in the view. I want to save the new coordinates to my Core Data but the values are returning 0 for the clip.xCoordinate and clip.yCoordinate when reloaded.

Below is where I would save the coordinates of the new position and I want to save the X and Y axis positions. Could it be I need to precise which button is being edited? or is it uIViewSelected.frame.midX?

```
@objc func handlePan(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer)
{
    let uIViewSelected = sender.view!
    let clip = Clip(context: self.context) //Core Data 

    switch sender.state {
    case .began, .changed :
        moveViewWithPan(view: uIViewSelected, sender: sender)
        break
    case .ended:
        clip.xCoordinate = uIViewSelected.frame.midX
        clip.yCoordinate = uIViewSelected.frame.midY
        self.saveClip()
        break
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

In the Core Data, I am saving the x and y coordinate separately if that helps.
- name
- xCoordinate
- yCoordinate

If anyone has a solution or can point me in the right direction that would be great! Thanks

EDIT

```
func saveClip() {

    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print ("Error Saving Context")
        print(error)
    }

}

func loadClip(with request: NSFetchRequest<Clip> = Clip.fetchRequest()) {

    do {
        clipArray = try context.fetch(request)
    } catch {
        print("Error Fetching data from context")
    }

}

func moveViewWithPan(view: UIView, sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)

    if let view = sender.view {
        view.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x + translation.x, y: view.center.y + translation.y)
    }

    sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: view)
}
```

Comment: As I understand your post, the problem is that something is *causing an error*.  On a good day, errors tell you why they are happening.  Please edit your post to include the attributes of this error, and any additional information you know about it, in particular; when/where this error occurs.

Comment: Sorry Jerry, It was poorly phrased by me. The values are returning 0 and I am not getting any error messages.

Comment: please share the code of `moveViewWithPan`

Comment: I'm more interested in the code of `Clip(context:)` and `Clip.saveClip()`.  And also, which *values are returning 0*, and where?

Comment: I added the code you asked for. Thanks for the help!